# How to create a tensor with an unknown dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I have a layer in my neural network with an output vector `x` of size `[?, N]`. (with first dimension for the batch size). I want declare a tensor of `ones` of the same size in the next layer (Lambda layer). I see that I cannot use `y = keras.backend.ones(x.shape)` as the batch size is only available in runtime. How can I create this tensor?

Comment: Have you tried `backend.ones_like(x)` instead?

Comment: @today I tried it and it works. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by today in the comments, `K.ones_like` works:

```
from keras import backend as K
a = K.placeholder(shape=(None, 5))
b = K.ones_like(a)
print(b.shape)

>> TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(5)])
```

Depending on the type of operation you're doing, you can also make a ones tensor of shape [N] and rely on broadcasting to save memory:

```
from keras import backend as K
a = K.placeholder(shape=(None, 5))
b = K.ones(a.shape[-1])
print(a + b)

>> <tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=(?, 5) dtype=float32>
```